# nginx Rewrite routes to redirect all .com/en pages to the .com version

Tags: ruby, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

This might has been asked before, but I can't find a solution that works.

A website supports multiple languages, **default** to **English**. How do I set up **nginx** rewrite command to route **.com/en/** to **.com**

E.g.

```
URL
 http://www.tender.com/en/any_path

Redirect URL:
 http://www.tender.com/any_path
```

Please note, i just want only /en (English) to route to without /en, while all other languages should be accessible with its shorts like /fr

I'm using following tools:

- **nginx(nginx/1.17.3)**
- **ruby(2.5.7)**
- **Rails(5.1.6.2)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved it. if anybody is facing same issue, can try to see, if this solution helps.

I kept it in a separate location block.

```
location /en {
  rewrite ^/en(/.*)$ $1 redirect;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
location /en {
  rewrite ^/en(/.*)$ $1 break;
}
```

try this one:

```
location /en {
  rewrite ^/en(/.*)$ $1 last;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working. I kept this in `server {}` block